# Why does booleans only work when it is surrounded in quotes with if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In any JS tutorial it says this:

"true/false is a datatype, it is not a string".

Why do I need to surround a bollean with quotes?

The  code is working but  it shouldn't work from what I understand.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Example
</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Sorry, this website is not for coding. It is for my testing
</p>
<button aria-pressed="false" onclick="myFunction()" id="buttona">
Notify Me by Email
</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
var a = document.getElementById('buttona');
var isPressed = a.getAttribute('aria-pressed');
if(isPressed == "false") {
    a.setAttribute('aria-pressed', "true");
}
else{
    a.setAttribute('aria-pressed', "false");
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I did my research but found nothing.

Comment: `a.getAttribute('aria-pressed')` returns a string, not a boolean

Comment: Using `false` in your code like this: `var a = false;` means `a` has now a boolean value, `false`. However HTML attributes are always strings, since HTML is text. Like VLAZ says, getting the attribute returns `"false"`, not `false`, if you will. This is similar to how an <input type="number">'s value will always be a string, like `"123"`. You need to turn that into an actual number first, in order to do calculations.